# how to set ng-model dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="(key, day) in {'monday':'Monday','tuesday':'Tuesday','wednesday':'Wednesday','thursday':'Thursday','friday':'Friday','saturday':'Saturday','sunday':'Sunday'}">
    <label for="{{key}}" class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{day | translate}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="wd.{{key}}" id="{{key}}" name="{{key}}" min="1" placeholder="{{'Enter the price' | translate}}" required />
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that I have an `ng-model` on the `input` which is trying to set the model dynamically `wd.{{key}}`.

When I run this code it says that there is an invalid property name after `.`.

How can I get the same effect? I don't like having HTML code for each day of the week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the bracket notation (and don't forget that it is still JavaScript):

```
ng-model="wd[key]"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller set

```
$scope.wd = [   {key: 'monday', day: 'Monday', value: ''},
                {key: 'tuesday', day: 'Tuesday', value: ''},
                ***
            ];
```

Then in the html

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="day_item in wd">
    <label for="{{day_item.key}}" class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{day_item.day | translate}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="day_item.value" id="{{day_item.key}}" name="{{day_item.key}}" min="1" placeholder="{{'Enter the price' | translate}}" required />
    </div>
</div>
```